# Texture Rendering in OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, textures

I am trying to render texture in openGL. My code is:

```
void startupDemo()
{
//  int x, y, z, i;

    time=0;
    timebase=0;
    frame=0;
    sprintf( fps_glut, "FPS:init in progress" );
    fpssss = 0.0;

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9) ;
    //loadTextures();

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    //glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Enable lighting //////////////
    //glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION, g_lightPosition);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, g_lightAmbient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, g_lightDiffuse);

    // Mesh texture loading ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if( g_texture_pixmap = BMP_Loader("dididj.jpg" ) )
    {
        glGenTextures( 1, &mesh.textureId );

        // Creation d'un nouvel objetde texture //////////////
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mesh.textureId);

        // Stockage des data dans le nouvel objetde texture .
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, g_texture_width, g_texture_height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g_texture_pixmap );
        printf( "\nLoading texture 1 on board ok." );

    }
    else
    {
        printf( "\nLoading texture 1 failed!" );
    }

    if( g_texture_pixmap )
    {
        delete [] g_texture_pixmap;
        g_texture_pixmap=NULL;
    }

    // Mesh texture loading ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if( g_texture_pixmap = BMP_Loader( "data/virus.bmp" ) )
    //if( g_texture_pixmap = BMP_Loader( "data/texture01.bmp" ) )
    {
        glGenTextures( 1, &g_texID );

        // Creation d'un nouvel objetde texture //////////////
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texID );

        // Stockage des data dans le nouvel objetde texture .
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, g_texture_width, g_texture_height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, g_texture_pixmap );
        printf( "\nLoading texture 2 on board ok." );

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

        // S et T : coordonnes du texel (texture element) ////////////////
        // GL_REPEAT:repetition du motif dans le sens des S (GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S)
        // ou des T (GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T) ///////////////////////////////////////
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

        // Positionne la fonction de texture active (cioe les valeurs des texels
        // peuvent moduler la couleur dans laquelle le polygone serait rendu en
        // l'absence de texture, ou plus simplement comment sont combinees les
        // valeurs des texels avec les valeurs chromatiques du fragment traite)... ouf!
        glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
        //glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

    }
    else
    {
        printf( "\nLoading texture 2 failed!" );
    }

    if( g_texture_pixmap )
    {
        delete [] g_texture_pixmap;
        g_texture_pixmap=NULL;
    }

/*
    if( mesh.load( "data/chrome_logo.asc" ) )
    {
        shutdownDemo();
        exit(0);
    }

    mesh.preProcess();

*/



    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            // Turn depth testing on

    // This is where we initialize our empty texture to be rendered too.
    // We pass in the texture array to store it, the texture size,
    // the channels (3 for R G B), the type of texture (RGB) and texture ID.
    CreateBlankRenderTexture( &g_tex_0_ID, 512, 3, GL_RGB);

    // Create the texture map for the spinning cube and assign it to texture ID 1
    //CreateTexture(g_Texture, "Brick.bmp", 1);
    g_tex_1_ID = g_texID;

}
```

I am new to OpenGL, I have tried debugging the code but still I am not getting the results. I have verified the parameters to functions are correct although I get the warning that:

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\cg\project\main.cpp||In function 'void startupDemo()':|
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\cg\project\main.cpp|744|warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\cg\project\main.cpp|768|warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|
```

I have seen this warning before also and I think it is harmless and so can't be a source of error.

WRT Weather Vane's comment: Program using this function works, doesn't crash except that the texture fails to load and on terminal "Texture loading failed"
gets printed.

Comment: This is a "something doesn't work" question. Does the program run but without textures? Does it crash? Does it give error messages?

Comment: The warnings can be fixed by changing the function signature of `BMP_Loader` from `BMP_Loader( char *name )` to `BMP_Loader( const char *name )`. The warning is harmless if and only if `BMP_Loader` doesn't attempt to modify the string.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes warning disappeared. But texture is still not working.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have edited the question at the end.

Comment: @Novak007: Well, maybe `BMP_Loader()` doesn't deal with JPEGs?

Comment: Your code logic says the fault is in `BMP_Loader()` returning `NULL` - your own function?

Comment: @derhass Even bmp is not working.

Comment: @WeatherVane It works byte by byte, I have posted link to full code at the top of the question. Please have a look. The output is fine, except that the object is without any texture.

Comment: for a tutorial on OpenGL textures using the modern pipeline approach battle through this tutorial ... these examples DO work just fine  http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/

Comment: @ScottStensland Tutorials are not helping. I have followed them, they explain the functions which I have verified . Please see the code at the link in the question.

Comment: assure you post your demo.h header file as is your above code link fails to compile without it

Comment: @ScottStensland Yes. please check it.

Comment: @ScottStensland 3 file demo.h main.cpp and glut.h are needed I have posted them, I would be grateful if youu could help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `BMP_Loader()` works with bitmap files, as its name suggests.

Its implementation contains references to bitmap structures with

```
data = (Byte_ *)(fileBuffer + sizeof(sBMP_header) + sizeof(sBMP_info) );
```

yet you are asking it to process JPG files.

Your above comment says even bitmap files do not work. Perhaps they are the wrong format (you test that). Perhaps the bitmap `struct` declarations are wrong (not posted, but I see the field names have been translated into French. Perhaps they should be `packed`. Perhaps the endianness of numerical fields is wrong.

Use a debugger, and find out **which line** is returning `NULL` from the function `BMP_Loader()`.

**UPDATE** - This example shows the difference of packing a `struct`. Without it, your declaration will not match the header format.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int Dword_;    // 32 bits
typedef unsigned short Word_;   // 16 bits
typedef unsigned char Byte_;    // 8 bits

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {      // my struct
    Word_  bfType;
    Dword_ bfSize;
    Word_  bfReserved1;
    Word_  bfReserved2;
    Dword_ bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)

struct sBMP_header                        // your struct
{
    Word_ codmag;
    Dword_ taille;
    Word_ reserv1;
    Word_ reserv2;
    Dword_ offsetImage;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf ("My struct size %d\n", sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    printf ("Your struct size %d\n", sizeof(struct sBMP_header));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
My struct size 14
Your struct size 16
```

I don't know what syntax your compiler would use to `pack` the struct (mine is MSVC). Without it, the next field after the solitary first `Word_` field is aligned to 32 bits, and the adjacent pair of `Word_` fields together take 32 bits, this explains the difference of 16 bits in size.

And the same goes for the other `structs`.

Comment: Please have a look at the header file.

Comment: I repeat: the structures must be **packed** and they are in little-endian format. `struct sBMP_header` is size 16, it should be size 14.

Comment: so i should make it size 14. Please elaborate a bit more. Thanks a lot .

Comment: struct sBMP_header
{       Dword_ taille;
        Dword_ offsetImage;
 Word_ codmag;
 Word_ reserv1;
 Word_ reserv2;
 
}; Is this fine ?